How can we solve this Array to string conversion error in PHP 8
I have this below code from old theme file. When migrating this to PHP 8, exactly at this line ($$value['id'] = get_option( $value['id'] ); }) it throws an error:
[error] 198034#198034: *334 FastCGI sent in stderr: "ng:  Array to string conversion
Any solution?
global $options, $value, $shortname;
foreach ($options as $value) {
    if (isset($value['id'])) {
        if ( get_option( $value['id'] ) === FALSE) {
            if (array_key_exists('std', $value)) { 
                update_option( $value['id'], $value['std'] );
                 $$value['id'] = $value['std'];
            }
        } else {
            $$value['id'] = get_option( $value['id'] ); }
    }
}


You could try un-setting the variable before assigning it. unset($$value['id']); before the line that throws an error/warning.

In PHP 8 (starting from PHP 7.0) do not use $$var instead use ${$var}. Therefore the code becomes:
global $options, $value, $shortname;
foreach ($options as $value) {
    if (isset($value['id'])) {
        if ( get_option( $value['id'] ) === FALSE) {
            if (array_key_exists('std', $value)) { 
                update_option( $value['id'], $value['std'] );
                 ${$value['id']} = $value['std'];
            }
        } else {
            ${$value['id']} = get_option( $value['id'] );
        }
    }
}

